# With the given Batch File, what does it do? How can I rewrite it to make it simpler?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

```
@echo off
set myvar5=
if "%1"=="" goto otherthingy
set myvar4=__HAHFDsdfasdfHADF__
set myvar1=%1%myvar4%
:thingy
set myvar2=%myvar1:~0,1%
set myvar5=%myvar2%%myvar5%
set myvar1=%myvar1:~1%
if not "%myvar1%"=="%myvar4%" goto thingy
echo %myvar5%
:otherthingy
```

With the given batch file, what does the batch file do? How can it be rewritten to make it simpler? What would it be if rewritten in Powershell?

Comment: How is this PHP Related? I cannot see anything similar to PHP other than `echo` and ``if` but that's similar in many languages. Removing the tag.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about why the code isn't working, but reviewing the code.  This should be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Here is, how you can shorten it:

```
@echo off
set "output="
if "%1"=="" goto otherthingy
set input=%1
:thingy
  set output=%input:~0,1%%output%
  set input=%input:~1%
  if not "%input%"=="" goto thingy
  echo %output%
:otherthingy
```

It takes every char from Input and adds it to the front of output, resulting in reversing the order (what Monacraft already stated).

(I renamed the variables for better readabiltiy)

Answer (score 0):

As to what your code does I believe it reverse a string inputted:

```
C:\> test.bat 1234567890
0987654321
```

As to how it works I made it print all the variables as it runs by adding an `echo` command and it just goes through ever letter and reverses it

**With**: (`Echo myvar2 = %myvar2%     myvar5 = %myvar5%     myvar1 = %myvar1%`)

```
C:\>test.bat 1234567890
myvar2 = 1     myvar5 = 1     myvar1 = 1234567890__HAHFDsdfasdfHADF__
myvar2 = 2     myvar5 = 21     myvar1 = 234567890__HAHFDsdfasdfHADF__
myvar2 = 3     myvar5 = 321     myvar1 = 34567890__HAHFDsdfasdfHADF__
myvar2 = 4     myvar5 = 4321     myvar1 = 4567890__HAHFDsdfasdfHADF__
myvar2 = 5     myvar5 = 54321     myvar1 = 567890__HAHFDsdfasdfHADF__
myvar2 = 6     myvar5 = 654321     myvar1 = 67890__HAHFDsdfasdfHADF__
myvar2 = 7     myvar5 = 7654321     myvar1 = 7890__HAHFDsdfasdfHADF__
myvar2 = 8     myvar5 = 87654321     myvar1 = 890__HAHFDsdfasdfHADF__
myvar2 = 9     myvar5 = 987654321     myvar1 = 90__HAHFDsdfasdfHADF__
myvar2 = 0     myvar5 = 0987654321     myvar1 = 0__HAHFDsdfasdfHADF__
0987654321
```

As for doing it more effectively, it has been programmed efficiently all ready. Don't see whats wrong with it.

Comment: well, at least you can remove the line `set myvar4=__HAHFDsdfasdfHADF__` and replace the line `if not "%myvar1%"=="%myvar4%" goto thingy` with `if not "%myvar1%"=="" goto thingy` without any loss of functionality

Comment: Yes, but the way he was asking it sounded like the code was dreadfully slow for him